# json array of complex object is always null on post

Tags: arrays, json, post, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My project: ASP.Net Web Api, Dot.Net Core 2.0, VS 2017.

This is my model:

```
public class AddressData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string complement { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] List<AddressData> value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return BadRequest();

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

This is my Json:

```
{
"value" : [
    {
        "id" : "08921619810",
        "address" : "ilicinia",
        "number" : 154,
        "complement": ""
    },
    {
        "id" : "12345678910",
        "address" : "candido figueiredo",
        "number" : 581,
        "complement": "ap 15"
    }
]
}
```

the request parameter 'value' is always NULL. If I change the controller method signature to

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] AddressData value)
```

remove and use the following Json

```
{
"id" : "08921619810",
"address" : "ilicinia",
"number" : 154,
"complement": ""
}
```

Everything works fine. If I change to [FromForm], it works, but the List of objects contains no elements (Count property = 0).

I'm using Postman, configured to send POST messages in "application/json" for content type.

Can someone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the object you're sending in JSON, and the C# POCO object you're trying to deserialise into. The JSON you're sending is not a list of AddressData, it is an object that looks like this is C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Yournamespace
{
    public class AddressDataList
    {
        public List<AddressData> value { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string complement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you change your controller to accept `AddressDataList`, it should now deserialize correctly:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] AddressDataList addressDataList)
    {
        if (addressDataList == null)
            return BadRequest();

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @tura08. Worked like magic. Just curious: If I'd want to receive a List<> directly within the **value** parameter, how would I have to format the json? Can you give me a little snippet of that?

Comment: A pure list is not valid JSON since there is no key for the list value. So you need to have a object that has a key with the name "value".